# iOS 16 - issue rendering images with certain image color profiles on the browser

Tags: ios, safari, jpeg

iOS 16 has issues rendering some jpgs with certain color profiles in browsers. For eg. Sierra Profiler Test (XYZ_2) Color Profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used exiftool to convert the color profile to : sRGB IEC61966-2.1, which was properly rendered.